# Fancyhdr doesn't work after first page

Tags: fancyhdr

I begin saying that I'm a LaTeX novice, I mostly try to emulate others' work to produce documents.

Then, I'm trying to write my master thesis. I'm trying to use the `fancyhdr` package and in my previous works it worked. However, here it does not.

I'm attaching my whole code, except for the written parts (of course)

Thanks a lot to anyone who could help me.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{[...]}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Myname}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.4ex} 
\linespread{1.5}
\newcommand{\spa}{\hspace{2cm}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    [...]
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\bigskip
    \textbf{Abstract}
\end{center}
[...]

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\tableofcontents  
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage
\setlength{\headsep}{1pt}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The European Union}
[...]
\end{document}
```

---

Here's what the output gives, I would like to have the headers/footers in both pages (and then on).
[image: Output]

Comment: `\pagestyle{fancy}`, not `\pagestyle{headings}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: The first page of a `\chapter` in `report` uses `plain`, so `\pagestyle{fancy}` would not work here (or `headings`)

Comment: Are you sure you want a header on the first page of chapters? This is not at all usual.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It will here because `plain` has been redefined to make no changes.

Comment: Is there any news here?